# Android ViewPager stop page change progress

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

In the ViewPager with Tablayout, when I change the page by clicking on tablayout or swiping, on the Page Change Event how can I check some conditions, if invalid stay on the current page (stop paging progress), unless going to the selected page.